# Ionic project running in android am facing this issues:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException:

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I have created project,in that ionic folder will be generated from siberian tool.while running the android folder in android studio,am facing this issue:Anyone help me please

Error:Execution failed for

> task:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'. 
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge
>   dex

Please kindly help me,even i given multidex enabled true also but still same problem,i clean and rebuild the project also.this is my gradle file`
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'    
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        // Required for 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.1.1'
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
        mavenCentral();
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}    
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.14.1'
}
http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html
ext {
    apply from: 'CordovaLib/cordova.gradle'

    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvCompileSdkVersion')) {
        cdvCompileSdkVersion = null;
    }        
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildToolsVersion')) {
        cdvBuildToolsVersion = null;
    }        
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvVersionCode')) {
        cdvVersionCode = null
    }        
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvMinSdkVersion')) {
        cdvMinSdkVersion = null
    }        
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildMultipleApks')) {
        cdvBuildMultipleApks = null
    }
    // .properties files to use for release signing.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile')) {
        cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = null
    }
    // .properties files to use for debug signing.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile')) {
        cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = null
    }
    // Set by build.js script.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildArch')) {
        cdvBuildArch = null
    }

    cdvPluginPostBuildExtras = []
}

apply from: "cordova-plugin-admobpro/base-build.gradle"
apply from: "cordova-hot-code-push-plugin/base-chcp.gradle"
apply from: "phonegap-plugin-push/base-push.gradle"
apply from: "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/base-barcodescanner.gradle"
apply from: "cordova-plugin-geofence/base-build.gradle"
// PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS END

def hasBuildExtras = file('build-extras.gradle').exists()
if (hasBuildExtras) {
    apply from: 'build-extras.gradle'
}

// Set property defaults after extension .gradle files.
if (ext.cdvCompileSdkVersion == null) {
    ext.cdvCompileSdkVersion = privateHelpers.getProjectTarget()
}
if (ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion == null) {
    ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion = privateHelpers.findLatestInstalledBuildTools()
}
if (ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('debug-signing.properties').exists()) {
    ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = 'debug-signing.properties'
}
if (ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('release-signing.properties').exists()) {
    ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = 'release-signing.properties'
}

// Cast to appropriate types.
ext.cdvBuildMultipleApks = cdvBuildMultipleApks == null ? false : cdvBuildMultipleApks.toBoolean();
ext.cdvMinSdkVersion = cdvMinSdkVersion == null ? null : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvMinSdkVersion)
ext.cdvVersionCode = cdvVersionCode == null ? null : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvVersionCode)

def computeBuildTargetName(debugBuild) {
    def ret = 'assemble'
    if (cdvBuildMultipleApks && cdvBuildArch) {
        def arch = cdvBuildArch == 'arm' ? 'armv7' : cdvBuildArch
        ret += '' + arch.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + arch.substring(1);
    }
    return ret + (debugBuild ? 'Debug' : 'Release')
}

// Make cdvBuild a task that depends on the debug/arch-sepecific task.
task cdvBuildDebug
cdvBuildDebug.dependsOn {
    return computeBuildTargetName(true)
}

task cdvBuildRelease
cdvBuildRelease.dependsOn {
    return computeBuildTargetName(false)
}

task cdvPrintProps << {
    println('cdvCompileSdkVersion=' + cdvCompileSdkVersion)
    println('cdvBuildToolsVersion=' + cdvBuildToolsVersion)
    println('cdvVersionCode=' + cdvVersionCode)
    println('cdvMinSdkVersion=' + cdvMinSdkVersion)
    println('cdvBuildMultipleApks=' + cdvBuildMultipleApks)
    println('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile)
    println('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile)
    println('cdvBuildArch=' + cdvBuildArch)
    println('computedVersionCode=' + android.defaultConfig.versionCode)
    android.productFlavors.each { flavor ->
        println('computed' + flavor.name.capitalize() + 'VersionCode=' + flavor.versionCode)
    }
}

android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2048m"
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId privateHelpers.extractStringFromManifest("package")
        multiDexEnabled true
        if (cdvMinSdkVersion != null) {
            minSdkVersion cdvMinSdkVersion
        }
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
    }
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'
    if (Boolean.valueOf(cdvBuildMultipleApks)) {
        productFlavors {
            armv7 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode * 10 + 2
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", ""
                }
            }
            x86 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode * 10 + 4
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "x86", ""
                }
            }
            all {
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "all", ""
                }
            }
        }
    }
    /*

    ELSE NOTHING! DON'T MESS WITH THE VERSION CODE IF YOU DON'T HAVE TO!

    else if (!cdvVersionCode) {
      def minSdkVersion = cdvMinSdkVersion ?: privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("minSdkVersion")
      // Vary versionCode by the two most common API levels:
      // 14 is ICS, which is the lowest API level for many apps.
      // 20 is Lollipop, which is the lowest API level for the updatable system webview.
      if (minSdkVersion >= 20) {
        defaultConfig.versionCode += 9
      } else if (minSdkVersion >= 14) {
        defaultConfig.versionCode += 8
      }
    }
    */
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    if (cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
        signingConfigs {
            release {
                // These must be set or Gradle will complain (even if they are overridden).
                keyAlias = ""
                keyPassword = "__unset"
                // And these must be set to non-empty in order to have the signing step added to the task graph.
                storeFile = null
                storePassword = "__unset"
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
        addSigningProps(cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.release)
    }
    if (cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile) {
        addSigningProps(cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.debug)
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    // debugCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug"))
    // releaseCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release"))
    implementation project(path: ':CordovaLib')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.2'
    compile 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.14@aar'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.0'
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
}

def promptForReleaseKeyPassword() {
    if (!cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
        return;
    }
    if ('__unset'.equals(android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword)) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = privateHelpers.promptForPassword('Enter key store password: ')
    }
    if ('__unset'.equals(android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword)) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = privateHelpers.promptForPassword('Enter key password: ');
    }
}

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
    taskGraph.getAllTasks().each() { task ->
        if (task.name == 'validateReleaseSigning' || task.name == 'validateSigningRelease') {
            promptForReleaseKeyPassword()
        }
    }
}

def addSigningProps(propsFilePath, signingConfig) {
    def propsFile = file(propsFilePath)
    def props = new Properties()
    propsFile.withReader { reader ->
        props.load(reader)
    }

    def storeFile = new File(props.get('key.store') ?: privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'storeFile'))
    if (!storeFile.isAbsolute()) {
        storeFile = RelativePath.parse(true, storeFile.toString()).getFile(propsFile.getParentFile())
    }
    if (!storeFile.exists()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException('Keystore file does not exist: ' + storeFile.getAbsolutePath())
    }
    signingConfig.keyAlias = props.get('key.alias') ?: privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'keyAlias')
    signingConfig.keyPassword = props.get('keyPassword', props.get('key.alias.password', signingConfig.keyPassword))
    signingConfig.storeFile = storeFile
    signingConfig.storePassword = props.get('storePassword', props.get('key.store.password', signingConfig.storePassword))
    def storeType = props.get('storeType', props.get('key.store.type', ''))
    if (!storeType) {
        def filename = storeFile.getName().toLowerCase();
        if (filename.endsWith('.p12') || filename.endsWith('.pfx')) {
            storeType = 'pkcs12'
        } else {
            storeType = signingConfig.storeType // "jks"
        }
    }
    signingConfig.storeType = storeType
}

for (def func : cdvPluginPostBuildExtras) {
    func()
}

// This can be defined within build-extras.gradle as:
//     ext.postBuildExtras = { ... code here ... }
if (hasProperty('postBuildExtras')) {
    postBuildExtras()
}
`
```

Please help me anyone

Answer (score 0):

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.2'   <--Change to 11.8.0
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'   <--Remove
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
```

Comment: but still same problem am facing